# Ajax laravel doesn't return single record in console but all data and nothing in html

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'am trying to make search function that user input code of product in textbox and click button to see detail of the product using ajax and laravel.

this is my route

```
Route::get('tracking', 'ClientController@show')->name('tracking');
```

and my controller (ClientController)

```
public function show(Request $request){
    $no_smu = $request->input('search');
    $tracking = Incoming::where('no_smu', 'like', '%' . $no_smu . '%')->get();
    return response()->json($tracking);
}
```

my form blade

```
<form class="lockscreen-credentials" id="form">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="no_smu" id="no_smu" class="form-control" placeholder="SMU Number">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right text-muted"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="help-block text-center" id="content">
 <!-- data should load here -->
</div>
```

ajax script

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

    $('#submit').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var no_smu = $('#no_smu').val();
      // alert(no_smu);
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{ route('tracking') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'no_smu' : no_smu},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          // $('#content').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

the problems, it return all data not a single data of input product and if i comment `console.log(data)` and uncommented `$('#content').html(data)` it's return nothing.

Comment: If you want single then use `first()` instead of `->get()`

Comment: @DilipHirapara wow, i forgot that part, thanks, now its return single data, but when i make it print on blade using $('#content').html(data) it doesn't return anything, is there something i miss? btw you can make an answer of my question, i'll vote it, :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a half day, I finally solved this.

Like @DilipHirapara suggested it should use `first()` to get single data. In my controller i called request input with wrong name with textbox in blade.

Now my controller

```
public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $no_smu = $request->input('no_smu');        
        $tracking = Incoming::where('no_smu', 'LIKE','%'. $no_smu .'%')->first();
        return response()->json($tracking); 
    }
```

and my form

```
<form class="lockscreen-credentials" id="form">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="no_smu" id="no_smu" class="form-control" placeholder="SMU Number">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right text-muted"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And for my ajax, i should add the item of my column with `data`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
        });

        $('#submit').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var no_smu = $('#no_smu').val();
          // alert(no_smu);
          $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "{{ url('tracking') }}",
            data: {'no_smu' : no_smu, "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
              $('#smu').html(data.no_smu);
              $('#flight').html("Flight number " + ": " + data.flight_no);
              $('#koli').html("Koli " + ": " + data.koli);
              $('#kilo').html("Kilo" + ": " + data.kilo);
              $('#asal').html("Asal" + ": " + data.asal);
              $('#status').html("Status" + ": " + data.status);
              // console.log(data.no_smu);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

in the process i faced `Error internal server 500` something like that.

to resolve this. add meta tag in head of html

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and add `"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"` with passing data in ajax like above.

Answer (score 1):

Make your controller code as below.

```
public function show(Request $request){
    $no_smu = $request->input('search');
    $tracking = Incoming::where('no_smu', 'like', '%' . $no_smu . '%')->first();
    return view('traking_data');
}
```

make one new view file under view folder, where you can add HTML to print

**traking_data.blade.php**

```
<div>
{{ $tracking->no_smu }}
</div>
```

It'll return HTML in ajax

```
$('#content').html(data)
```

Comment: should the show function in controller passing data to blade using compact or with?
cause i got error undefined variable,

and my blade name is client.blade.php under subfolder name tracking, 
so it should be 
return view('tracking.client', compact($tracking));
or 
return view('tracking.client')->with('tracking', $tracking);

but it still didn't work to passing to blade.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention compact :) and  you have to make new view file that will return only HTML which you'll show in `tracking.client` file

Comment: It still didn't return anything, even it's like not response at all, 
i've changed my controller like you suggested, with `compact` so it's like

`return view('tracking.show', compact($tracking));` . 

for record, before i post this question i've try with compact, but it seem not to be the problem, i thought it was the ajax code maybe,